# Chamisha Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we are in the month of Adar

Adar = 205

Answer (score 4):

Avraham's father Terach died at the age of 205. Bereishit 11:32

Answer (score 1):

http://dafyomi.shemayisrael.co.il/parsha/vayera3.htm

Avraham Avinu called the Makom HaMikdash "Har". Har = 205

Yitchok Avinu called it "Sadeh"

Yaakov Avinu called it "Bayis"

> Avraham Avinu came and prayed on the
>   place where the Temple was to be,
>   opposite the heavenly Temple, and with
>   his prayers he added an additional
>   wall to the heavenly Temple -- a
>   second Machaneh of angels. Machaneh
>   (103) plus Machaneh (another 103)
>   equals 206. That is why Avraham called
>   it a "Har" [= mountain], the Gematria
>   of which is 205 (He = 5, Resh = 200.
>   One of the rules of Gematria is that
>   one may, at times, add 1 to the
>   combined numerical value of a word's
>   letters. This extra 1 corresponds to
>   the word as a whole. Adding an extra 1
>   in such a manner is referred to as "Im
>   Hakollel" [= with the total]. In such
>   a manner, the word "Har" equals
>   exactly 206, or 2x103.)
>
> Yitzchak prayed there and added
>   another Machaneh of angels to the
>   Heavenly Beit Hamikdash, giving it a
>   third "wall." Now that there were
>   three Machanot, he referred to it as a
>   "Sadeh" [= field] which has the
>   Gematria of 309 (Sin = 300, Dalet = 4,
>   He = 5), or three times Machaneh
>   (103).
>
> When Yakov prayed there he added a
>   fourth wall, making it a "Bayit" [=
>   house], which has the Gematria of four
>   times Machaneh (103), or 412 (Beit =
>   2, Yud = 10, Taf = 400).
>
> The Belzer Rebbe adds that the
>   heavenly Beit Hamikdash did not yet
>   have a ceiling -- just as the
>   tabernacle in the desert had four
>   walls but no ceiling, only a covering
>   of cloth. Later on, before Moshe
>   Rabbeinu was taken away from the Bnei
>   Yisrael, he was shown all of Eretz
>   Yisrael [= the Land of Israel],
>   including the place of the Beit
>   Hamikdash (Rashi, Devarim 3:25). At
>   that time Moshe Rabbeinu also prayed
>   for the completion of the heavenly
>   Beit Hamikdash. He prayed using the
>   word, "Va'etchanan [= and I pleaded]"
>   (Devarim 3:23). He used this word
>   because his prayer was to add a
>   ceiling -- a fifth Machaneh of angels
>   -- to the heavenly Beit Hamikdash. Five times Machaneh is 515, exactly
>   the Gematria of "Va'etchanan" (Vav =
>   6, Alef = 1, Taf = 400, Chet = 8, Nun
>   = 50, Nun = 50)!

Comment: I actually just learned this part of Yeshaya yesterday. Check out Abarbanel for a great explanation of a very similar medrash.

Answer (score 0):

> An important method for addressing
>   Israel’s water shortage is utilizing
>   high-quality purified water for
>   agriculture in place of scarce and
>   expensive fresh water. Through its
>   Israeli counterpart, Keren Kayemeth
>   LeIsrael (KKL), JNF has already
>   invested $75 million for the
>   construction of **205** reservoirs in
>   Israel, which serve as the final stage
>   in the water purification process and
>   hold 66 billion gallons of recycled
>   water and flood runoff for
>   agriculture. These reservoirs increase
>   Israel’s total water supply by 12%,
>   providing almost half of the water
>   used by the agricultural sector and
>   saving enough fresh water for 1.5
>   million people a year. The JNF Parsons
>   Water Fund has committed to continuing
>   this work by building an additional 40
>   reservoirs.

http://www.jnf.org/work-we-do/our-projects/water/jnf-parsons-water-fund.html